# Using image resource in XAML markup?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add little icons to my tabs in WPF but having trouble with how to set up the binding.

```
<TabItem.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Image Source="{Binding Source=prop:Resources.eye}" />
          <Label VerticalAlignment="Center">Header</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem.Header>
```

The xmlns:prop is set up for the local project's Properties, I am pulling other values from it elsewhere so I know that the namespace works.  The markup above compiles fine BUT I don't see the eye image in the tab.

**Also**, is there any way to set this up into a template?  I'm fairly new to XAML/WPF and each tab will have its own image...

Comment: You have what in Resources.eye ? Uri, file name, BitmapImage ?
More details will help...

Answer (score 2):

Use this code. It will work :)

```
<TabItem.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Resources.eye}}" />
          <Label VerticalAlignment="Center">Header</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem.Header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Guessing without sufficient detail in your question, but you're setting the source of the binding to the `string` "prop:Resources.eye". What you want to do is resolve the `string` into the resource and assign that as the source:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource prop:Resources.eye}}" />
```